# Prove that $H=V$ if $H$ is an $n$-dimensional subspace of an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Prove that $H=V$ if $H$ is an $n$-dimensional subspace of an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$.

---

I am not exactly sure what to do to show that $H=V$.

So far I have reasoned that since $H$ and $V$ are $n$-dimensional, $\dim(H)=\dim(V)=n$. So the basis of $H$ and $V$ both contain $n$ vectors. From here do I need to show that every vectors in $H$ and $V$ are the same? Or can we simply conclude that since the basis of $H$ and $V$ contains the same number of vectors, $H=V$?

Comment: Each basis of $H$ is a basis of $V$, thus, $H=V$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ be a basis of $H$. Let $v\in V$. By definition the set $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n,v$ is linearly dependent since it is a set of $n+1$ vectors in $V$, so some vector in the sequence can be expressed as a linear combination of the vectors before it. Since the basis itself is linearly independent, this means that $v$ can be expressed in terms of the basis, hence $v\in H$.

Comment: Just wanted to add, you proved that $ V \subseteq H$. Just to finish off the proof, the converse $H \subseteq V$ is trivially true by the definition of subspace. Specifically, since $H$ was given as a subspace of $V$, and a subspace is by definition a subset, we immediately get $H \subseteq V$.

Answer (score 1):

Using bases might complicate things more than necessary. Here's another approach:

**Proving $H=V$:**

Suppose that $H\subsetneq V$. Then there is a vector $v\in V$ such that $v\not\in H$. Consider the subspace $\langle H,v\rangle$: since $v\not\in H$, we must have $\dim \langle H,v\rangle >\dim H$. This is a contradiction for the following reason:
$$
H\subset \langle H,v\rangle\subset V\implies n=\dim H\leq \dim \langle H,v\rangle\leq \dim V=n.
$$